# Pressure of condensation of an air parcel

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, thermodynamics, radiosounding

If a parcel of air ascends adiabatically, would condensation be reached at the lifting condensation level (LCL) or the level of free condensation (LFC)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lifting condensation level (LCL) is the level at which a rising particle reaches 100 % relative humidity by adiabatic cooling.

Please have a look at Wikipedia: [LCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifted_condensation_level) and [LFC (level of free convection!)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_free_convection).

Answer (score 4):

The LCL is the "lifted" level at which mechanical lifting mechanisms (frontal/dynamic or orographic) must raise a parcel to reach its dew point temperature, 100% relative humidity or saturation by adiabatic cooling. Alternatively, when a parcel of air is lifted due to heating from below, the parcel must rise to the convective condensation level (CCL) to reach saturation. (lifting due to buoyancy)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convective_condensation_level 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifted_condensation_level